# Migration upon adding a new field with Ignore in ORM Room DB

Tags: android, orm, android-room

I want to know if I add a new attribute/field to existing Entity and mark that new field as @Ignore. Do I require to write migration for new field, so it works for Old users when they update my android app.

```
@Entity(tableName = "places")
data class PlacesEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name ="p_id")  var id: Int = 0,
    var url: String? = "",
    var ownerAccountId: Long? = null,
    var creationType: Int,
    @Ignore var isSelected :Boolean = false)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You do not need any migration as you did not change the table schema.
>   You just added a variable with a ignore annotation.

See `@ignore` doc [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Ignore).

> Ignores the marked element from Room's processing logic.
>
> This annotation can be used in multiple places where Room processor
>   runs. For instance, you can add it to a field of an Entity and Room
>   will not persist that field.

Answer (score 0):

`@Ignore` will work in your case because what basically it does is just ignore the field and
  and i won't insert in table and it will work fine with existing user and even if you miss
  the `@Ignore` keyword and try to run app with old user login it will simply give you 
  exception(This is what happened in my case at least).

> @Ignore : This annotation can be used in multiple places where Room
>   processor runs. For instance, you can add it to a field of an Entity
>   and Room will not persist that field